# marmalade GCC ARC build

Tags: c++, build, automatic-ref-counting, cocos2d-x, marmalade

Can some one help me with this error! it seems like marmalade cant find the pilist.

Current Build: GCC ARM Release (Tue Nov 25 12:49:05 2014)

ERROR: exception occured in s3e_deploy 
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "D:\Marmalade\7.4\s3e\bin\\..\..\s3e\deploy\main.py", line 594, in 
main() 
File "D:\Marmalade\7.4\s3e\bin\\..\..\s3e\deploy\main.py", line 568, in main 
run() 
File "D:\Marmalade\7.4\s3e\bin\\..\..\s3e\deploy\main.py", line 544, in run 
do_action(settings) 
File "D:\Marmalade\7.4\s3e\bin\\..\..\s3e\deploy\main.py", line 461, in do_action 
deploy.deploy_to_folder(settings, myargs, False, True if options.copy_manifest else False) 
File "e:\9f402e98\s3e\deploy\common.py", line 1668, in deploy_to_folder 
File "e:\9f402e98\s3e\deploy\common.py", line 1563, in sign_and_embed 
File "e:\9f402e98\s3e\deploy\plugins\iphone\iphone.py", line 435, in deploy_to_folder 
File "D:\Marmalade\7.4\s3e\python\lib\shutil.py", line 208, in copytree 
raise Error, errors 
shutil.Error: [('deployments\\default\\iphone\\release\\intermediate_files\\TexturePacker\\Sprites\\CrumblingPlatform\\CrumblingPlatform.plist', u'deployments\\default\\iphone\\release\\intermediate_files\\gamercamp.app\\TexturePacker\\Sprites\\CrumblingPlatform\\CrumblingPlatform.plist', "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'deployments\\\\default\\\\iphone\\\\release\\\\intermediate_files\\\\gamercamp.app\\\\TexturePacker\\\\Sprites\\\\CrumblingPlatform\\\\CrumblingPlatform.plist'"), ('deployments\\default\\iphone\\release\\intermediate_files\\TexturePacker\\Sprites\\CrumblingPlatform\\CrumblingPlatform.png', u'deployments\\default\\iphone\\release\\intermediate_files\\gamercamp.app\\TexturePacker\\Sprites\\CrumblingPlatform\\CrumblingPlatform.png', "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'deployments\\\\default\\\\iphone\\\\release\\\\intermediate_files\\\\gamercamp.app\\\\TexturePacker\\\\Sprites\\\\CrumblingPlatform\\\\CrumblingPlatform.png'"), ('deployments\\default\\iphone\\release\\intermediate_files\\TexturePacker\\Sprites\\InvisibleBlocker\\InvisibleBlocker.plist', u'deployments\\default\\iphone\\release\\intermediate_files\\gamercamp.app\\TexturePacker\\Sprites\\InvisibleBlocker\\InvisibleBlocker.plist', "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'deployments\\\\default\\\\iphone\\\\release\\\\intermediate_files\\\\gamercamp.app\\\\TexturePacker\\\\Sprites\\\\InvisibleBlocker\\\\InvisibleBlocker.plist'"), ('deployments\\default\\iphone\\release\\intermediate_files\\TexturePacker\\Sprites\\InvisibleBlocker\\InvisibleBlocker.png', u'deployments\\default\\iphone\\release\\intermediate_files\\gamercamp.app\\TexturePacker\\Sprites\\InvisibleBlocker\\InvisibleBlocker.png', "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'deployments\\\\default\\\\iphone\\\\release\\\\intermediate_files\\\\gamercamp.app\\\\TexturePacker\\\\Sprites\\\\InvisibleBlocker\\\\InvisibleBlocker.png'"), ('deployments\\default\\iphone\\release\\intermediate_files\\TexturePacker\\Sprites\\InvisiblePlatform\\InvisiblePlatform.plist', u'deployments\\default\\iphone\\release\\intermediate_files\\gamercamp.app\\TexturePacker\\Sprites\\InvisiblePlatform\\InvisiblePlatform.plist', "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'deployments\\\\default\\\\iphone\\\\release\\\\intermediate_files\\\\gamercamp.app\\\\TexturePacker\\\\Sprites\\\\InvisiblePlatform\\\\InvisiblePlatform.plist'"), ('deployments\\default\\iphone\\release\\intermediate_files\\TexturePacker\\Sprites\\InvisiblePlatform\\InvisiblePlatform.png', u'deployments\\default\\iphone\\release\\intermediate_files\\gamercamp.app\\TexturePacker\\Sprites\\InvisiblePlatform\\InvisiblePlatform.png', "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'deployments\\\\default\\\\iphone\\\\release\\\\intermediate_files\\\\gamercamp.app\\\\TexturePacker\\\\Sprites\\\\InvisiblePlatform\\\\InvisiblePlatform.png'"), ('deployments\\default\\iphone\\release\\intermediate_files\\TexturePacker\\Sprites\\InvisibleWall\\invisibleWall.plist', u'deployments\\default\\iphone\\release\\intermediate_files\\gamercamp.app\\TexturePacker\\Sprites\\InvisibleWall\\invisibleWall.plist', "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'deployments\\\\default\\\\iphone\\\\release\\\\intermediate_files\\\\gamercamp.app\\\\TexturePacker\\\\Sprites\\\\InvisibleWall\\\\invisibleWall.plist'"), ('deployments\\default\\iphone\\release\\intermediate_files\\TexturePacker\\Sprites\\PlatformCrumbling\\Left', u'deployments\\default\\iphone\\release\\intermediate_files\\gamercamp.app\\TexturePacker\\Sprites\\PlatformCrumbling\\Left', "[Error 206] The filename or extension is too long: u'deployments\\\\default\\\\iphone\\\\release\\\\intermediate_files\\\\gamercamp.app\\\\TexturePacker\\\\Sprites\\\\PlatformCrumbling\\\\Left'"), ('deployments\\default\\iphone\\release\\intermediate_files\\TexturePacker\\Sprites\\PlatformCrumbling\\Middle', u'deployments\\default\\iphone\\release\\intermediate_files\\gamercamp.app\\TexturePacker\\Sprites\\PlatformCrumbling\\Middle', "[Error 206] The filename or extension is too long: u'deployments\\\\default\\\\iphone\\\\release\\\\intermediate_files\\\\gamercamp.app\\\\TexturePacker\\\\Sprites\\\\PlatformCrumbling\\\\Middle'"), ('deployments\\default\\iphone\\release\\intermediate_files\\TexturePacker\\Sprites\\PlatformCrumbling\\Right', u'deployments\\default\\iphone\\release\\intermediate_files\\gamercamp.app\\TexturePacker\\Sprites\\PlatformCrumbling\\Right', "[Error 206] The filename or extension is too long: u'deployments\\\\default\\\\iphone\\\\release\\\\intermediate_files\\\\gamercamp.app\\\\TexturePacker\\\\Sprites\\\\PlatformCrumbling\\\\Right'"), ('deployments\\default\\iphone\\release\\intermediate_files\\TexturePacker\\Sprites\\PlatformSlippery\\Left', u'deployments\\default\\iphone\\release\\intermediate_files\\gamercamp.app\\TexturePacker\\Sprites\\PlatformSlippery\\Left', "[Error 206] The filename or extension is too long: u'deployments\\\\default\\\\iphone\\\\release\\\\intermediate_files\\\\gamercamp.app\\\\TexturePacker\\\\Sprites\\\\PlatformSlippery\\\\Left'"), ('deployments\\default\\iphone\\release\\intermediate_files\\TexturePacker\\Sprites\\PlatformSlippery\\Middle', u'deployments\\default\\iphone\\release\\intermediate_files\\gamercamp.app\\TexturePacker\\Sprites\\PlatformSlippery\\Middle', "[Error 206] The filename or extension is too long: u'deployments\\\\default\\\\iphone\\\\release\\\\intermediate_files\\\\gamercamp.app\\\\TexturePacker\\\\Sprites\\\\PlatformSlippery\\\\Middle'"), ('deployments\\default\\iphone\\release\\intermediate_files\\TexturePacker\\Sprites\\PlatformSlippery\\Right', u'deployments\\default\\iphone\\release\\intermediate_files\\gamercamp.app\\TexturePacker\\Sprites\\PlatformSlippery\\Right', "[Error 206] The filename or extension is too long: u'deployments\\\\default\\\\iphone\\\\release\\\\intermediate_files\\\\gamercamp.app\\\\TexturePacker\\\\Sprites\\\\PlatformSlippery\\\\Right'"), ('deployments\\default\\iphone\\release\\intermediate_files\\TexturePacker\\Sprites\\StandardPlatform\\StandardPlatform.plist', u'deployments\\default\\iphone\\release\\intermediate_files\\gamercamp.app\\TexturePacker\\Sprites\\StandardPlatform\\StandardPlatform.plist', "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'deployments\\\\default\\\\iphone\\\\release\\\\intermediate_files\\\\gamercamp.app\\\\TexturePacker\\\\Sprites\\\\StandardPlatform\\\\StandardPlatform.plist'"), ('deployments\\default\\iphone\\release\\intermediate_files\\TexturePacker\\Sprites\\StandardPlatform\\StandardPlatform.png', u'deployments\\default\\iphone\\release\\intermediate_files\\gamercamp.app\\TexturePacker\\Sprites\\StandardPlatform\\StandardPlatform.png', "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'deployments\\\\default\\\\iphone\\\\release\\\\intermediate_files\\\\gamercamp.app\\\\TexturePacker\\\\Sprites\\\\StandardPlatform\\\\StandardPlatform.png'")]
```

Comment: The troublesome paths all seem to have double-escaped backslashes, `\\\\`, while the others don't.

Comment: Any idea how I can fix it?

Comment: I would try cleaning out the deployments directory and the build directory and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Python function copytree() generation an exception. Maybe in your case it is too large length of file's path. Try move your project closer to the root directory of drive